# Microsoft Excel - Interactive Average

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, interactive

Its for an assignment. There are data given for january to June , and July data is empty. After I enter July data average is created.

Task is I have to fix a program, that after I put data in july a separate row of August is created and when I put data in august average is created and September row comes.

I am not asking for any code. Just point me in right direction where can I start from .

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill: Why do I always see that comment. This may not be a script writing service, but if users are willing to write codes, then why discourage them. If someone wants to write scripts as a training, then I think we should welcome them, after all writing an answer like a formula is no different in effort from writing a script.

Comment: @Firee Posting an already written script and asking for help is fine. Posting no script and asking is to do all the work is not fine. Posting without even trying anything at all is not fine.

Comment: @Firee (cont) People are expected to at least do some research and make an effort - as is clearly pointed out in [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: @DavidPostill So you mean to say, users should not answer such type of questions? Then there should be similar rule for answering also, don't you think. In this case, your comment has gone waste, coz we have an excellent answer below.

Comment: @Firee There is always somebody who wants to answer a bad question and now the OP now has the answer for his homework :/

Comment: @DavidPostill Which makes the rule ineffective. In such cases,  should the answer be deleted?

Comment: @Firee It does not mean that the answer should be deleted, but it shows that people are willing to help even though the OP has not shown any research effort.  It may not happen all the time. By the way, we are here to share solutions. IMHO, if I pass my homework to you will you be willing to do it every single time?

Comment: @jcbermu As the one who answered the question,  I would like to let you know that I am willing to help even when the OP is not showing his research because: A) This answer could be valuable for other people in the future. B) It could be a starting point for the OP to get into the subject he's asking for. And C)  I'm rewarded with reputation points.

Comment: @Firee, the answer is NOT deleted. It is **put on hold**. If the user simply edit's their post to show what they had tried (or what ever is needed to make it on topic), it can be re-opened. In this case it's not effective (since OP has it's answer), I agree with you, but, it must be shown as "on hold" for other visitors who can see what type of questions are on / off topic here :) Asking to see the code they've tried doesn't discourage them as David did, it's just a request to see their code. If they didn't write any, then I will assume they were not very encouraged to start with !!

Answer (score 1):

This code does the task:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) ' It is executed each time there is a change on the sheet
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'Disable detection of further events
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet 'Assign a variable name to the active sheet
    Dim months(1 To 12) As String ' Creates an array of 12 elements to store month names
    months(1) = "january"
    months(2) = "february"
    months(3) = "march"
    months(4) = "april"
    months(5) = "may"
    months(6) = "june"
    months(7) = "july"
    months(8) = "august"
    months(9) = "september"
    months(10) = "october"
    months(11) = "november"
    months(12) = "december"
    totalrows = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Row of the last value entered
    If totalrows <= 12 Then 'If it is inside the defined range of months
        wks.Cells(totalrows + 1, 1) = months(totalrows) 'Put the next month name
        For j = totalrows + 2 To 13 'Cleans the rows below this
            wks.Cells(j, 1) = ""
        Next j
    End If
    dataAverage = 0 'calculate the average
    For i = 2 To totalrows
        dataAverage = dataAverage + wks.Cells(i, 2)
    Next i
    dataAverage = dataAverage / (totalrows - 1)
    wks.Cells(2, 5) = dataAverage 'Put the average in the designated cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'Enable the detection of events

ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'Whenever the Sub generates an error executes this line
End Sub
```

It works with a sheet like this:

[image]

You can customize the code to adapt it to a different position of rows /columns.

Open VBA / Macros with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F11</kbd>, double click the worksheet that you want to use and paste the code on the right side.

Comment: Excellent solution, though I'm not the OP. I see lot of good code writing guidelines there, good stuff.

Comment: I don't get this *Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)* in my VBA editor as the first line. For me it is just *Sub _procedure_name_()*. What am I missing?

Comment: *Private* macros doesn't show in the macro options by default.

Mark it private if you consider that it doesn't need to be accessed manually by the user.

*Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)* indicates that it is going to be executed every time a change happens.

Comment: thank you jcbermu :) . can you refer me some books that will help with learning the use of vba in excel.

Comment: @AshimKundu I don't know a book about it. But a good starting point is [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html)